# How to know the exact number of elements in an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

If I mention

```
int ar[100]={1,1};
```

and I want to know the number of elements present in it rather than the size of it, what commands should I use?

Comment: the rest 98 numbers are filled with 0s. you can use a loop to count non-zeros, if you want to.

Comment: @user3528438 not necessarily. There might be garbage values in there

Comment: @asdf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c

Comment: @asdf the second line of that answer quotes: `int myArray[10] = { 1, 2 }; // initialize to 1,2,0,0,0...`

Comment: The number of elements is 100.

Comment: @asdf No, not unless you put garbage values in there explicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of an *array*, the size is always the number of elements multiplied by the size of each element. Neither of them (number of element or size) vary, once it is defined.

If you meant to find out the *meaningful* (to you) elements present in the array, well, you need to have a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) somewhere (thereby marking the end of valid data entry), and using a loop, you need to count the valid elements yourself.

Comment: In case of `strlen()` the sentinel value is the `\0` byte

Answer (score 2):

```
int array[3] = {1,2}; //1,2,0
```

Since the default initializes the array elements to 0, you can count the non-zero values to be the number of elements.

But, consider

```
int array[4] = {0,1,2}; //0,1,2,0
```

You'll need a way to determine which zeros are the meaningful ones. Probably, the last zeros are useless.

But consider

```
int array[4] = {0,1,0}; //0,1,0,0
```

The 0 at `array[2]` is intentional. Different ball game. It all depends on you to determine which zeros matter.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement some sort of counter to track the number of present elements as you add them. There is memory allocated for each element so it is nearly impossible to try and figure out how many of those memory slots are filled.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't give it the size, like:

```
int foo[]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

then compiler will allocate `foo` to just enough to hold the values in your initializer list, so when you do `sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0])` it will do what you want, as long as the array doesn't decay to a pointer. And it actually saves a lot of memory compared with hard coding a `100`.